# Is std::make_optional with an aggregate type legal in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, aggregate-initialization

Assume the following code snippet:

```
#include <optional>

struct MyStruct
{
//    MyStruct(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

int main()
{
   std::optional<MyStruct> ms1 = std::make_optional<MyStruct>(1);  

   std::optional<MyStruct> ms2{2};

   std::optional<MyStruct> ms3;
   ms3.emplace(3);

   std::optional<MyStruct> ms4(std::in_place, 4);
}
```

This works as intended using c++20 with gcc 11.2, all of those four creation methods fail compilation on clang ([Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/Med9YcqE6))

To make it work with clang, I need to uncomment the constructor.

My main question is: Which compiler is correct, clang or gcc?

Follow-up question: If clang is correct, is there any way to create a struct without constructor in an optional, without copying the struct into it, e.g. `std::optional<MyStruct> ms{MyStruct{3}}`?

Comment: Issue might be reduced to `MyStruct(42)` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PdcW9W8fG).

Comment: @Jarod42: I was going to ask what you meant, but then I took the reference, so I guess the answer is not meant to be taken seriously...

Comment: In C++20, aggregate initialization can be used with `(..)` instead of `{..}`. And internally std containers (as `std::optional`) use `()` (and not `{}`) to construct user-object.

Comment: I may be dense, but I still don't see that this explains how my issue can be reduced @Jarod42. The issue is still that initializing optional like this is impossible with clang for now, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible, as for `std::vector`, `std::map`, ... `std::optional` would do something like `new (&buffer) MyStruct(args...)`. So main issue is that `MyStruct(42)` is a C++20 feature, not yet implemented by Clang. `std::optional` didn't change in that regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My main question is: Which compiler is correct, clang or gcc?

GCC is correct. Since Clang has not yet implemented [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html), this will cause the following assert to fail and disable the `optional`'s constructor:

```
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<MyStruct, int>);
```

> is there any way to create a struct without constructor in an
> optional, without copying the struct into it?

Before Clang completes the P0960, I think there is no way. But since `MyStruct{3}` is an rvalue, it will *move* into `optional`.