# Why is std::is_constructible not true for a trivial aggregate type?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, aggregate-initialization

In regards to C++17; GCC, Clang, and MSVC consider a trival class type **not** to be constructible by any of its data member types. Since C++20, GCC and MSVC changed this, allowing the [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ae4vjsKEo) below to compile.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct t {
    int a;
};

static_assert(std::is_constructible<t, int>{});
```

Unfortunately, Clang seems to disagree and rejects this code when compiling with `-std=c++20` as well. Is this a compiler bug of Clang? And why do all compilers **not** consider a type like `t` to be constructible with an `int` when compiling with `-std=c++17`? After all, `t{0}` seems to be pretty constructible that way.

Comment: "Constructible" checks `( )`, not `{ }`, and Clang doesn't implement C++20 `( )` initialization for aggregates yet.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550439/in-place-creation-of-stdoptionalmystruct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructibility is based on the ability to use constructor syntax (`T(values)`). In C++20, aggregates can be initialized using constructor syntax, but in C++17 and before, they *must* use `{}` syntax.

Clang's C++20 implementation is simply not up to the standard yet.

Answer (score -1):

Clang will compile this if you add a constructor that can construct a `t` from an `int`. I'm not sure why this would not work without it in clang.

Comment: *"I'm not sure why this would not work without it in clang."* -- considering that the question is why this does not work in clang, this answer does not seem to answer the question. You have addressed *how* to make it work in clang, but the question is "why".